# left transition not working both ways (works left to right but not the other way around)

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-position, margin

I use position `relative` and `absolute` on the switch and handle respectively, then use `left` on the handle to move it to the end or start of 'cSwitch' but the transition duration i applied only works from left to right.

*i tried applying `right` too but that didn't change anything.*

```js
const cSwitch = document.querySelectorAll('.cSwitch')[0];

cSwitch.onclick = () => {
  
  (cSwitch.getAttribute('state') === 'on') ? cSwitch.setAttribute('state', 'off') : cSwitch.setAttribute('state', 'on');

}
```

```css
.cSwitch{
    
    position: relative;
    
    width: 150px;
    aspect-ratio: 2/1;
    
    border-radius: 50px 50px;
  
  background: crimson;
    
}

.cSwitch[state = on] .cSwitch_handle{
    
    position: absolute;
    
    left: 50%;
    
}

.cSwitch_handle{
    
    width: 75px;
    aspect-ratio: 1;
    
    border-radius: 50%;
    
    background: skyblue;
    
    left: 0%;
    
    transition: left 0.5s;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="switch-wrapper">
                            
    <div class="cSwitch" state="off" id="neon-switch">
         <div class="cSwitch_handle"></div>
    </div>
                        
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You neglected to apply `position: absolute` in the default state, so `left` has no effect. `left` may transition from `50%` back to `0%`- but it doesn't *apply*, because the element is not positioned.

Put `position: absolute` into the rule with the `.cSwitch_handle` selector instead.